# Where is the first reference to the "Z combinator", a call-by-value fix-point combinator?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, mathematical-logic, computer-science, computation

I'd like to know the earliest reference to the Z-combinator. This could be either where the name was first coined, or even the first discussion of a need for [an applicative-order Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Strict_fixed_point_combinator). I didn't find anything in Barendregt, which was my obvious place to look, nor did I see it in Curry's Combinatory Logic books.

Can someone point me the right direction?

Comment: The paper [History of Lambda-calculus and Combinatory Logic](http://www.users.waitrose.com/~hindley/SomePapers_PDFs/2006CarHin,HistlamRp.pdf) may provide some useful background.  It states that the Y combinator first appeared in Rosenbloom's *Elements of Mathematical Logic* of 1950, following Turing's introduction of a fixed-point combinator. It became know as Curry's Y.